# BULK API Status Not Found

Tags: apex, bulk-api

A simple bulk API which I am trying to create a JOB, and I am getting the status "NOT FOUND" and code: 400.

The same request working in the Workbench. Not sure what I am missing.

**bulkApiController.createJob('POST');**

> System.HttpResponse[Status=Not Found, StatusCode=404]

```
private static final string RESOURCE_URI = '/services/data/46.0/jobs/ingest';

    public static HTTPResponse createJob(String method){
        String baseURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
        String endpoint = baseURL+RESOURCE_URI;        

        String reqBody ='{"operation" : "insert","object" : "Account","contentType" : "CSV","lineEnding" : "CRLF"}';


        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();  
        req.setMethod(method);
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);   
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
        req.setBody(reqBody);


        Http httpReq = new Http();  
        HTTPResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        try{         
            res = httpReq.send(req);   
            System.debug('endpoint: '+res.toString());        
        }catch(System.CalloutException e) {
            System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
            System.debug(res.toString());
        }
        return res;

    }
```

Comment: When are you getting this error? Are you running it through anonymous apex and what are you passing as the "method" in the parameter

Comment: yes, anonymous. bulkApiController.createJob('POST')

Comment: Do you still get the same issue if you change the 'Content-Type' header to be application/xml? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/async_api_headers_content_type.htm

Comment: yes, I get the same issue, even though I change the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to add v to the version to work.
/services/data/**v46.0**/jobs/ingest